# Laravel: Post Array of Objects

Tags: laravel

Im in trouble with this code, I cant store my dataP array objects into mysql.

Ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/register/addpostulantR',
    method:'post',
    dataType: "text",
    data:JSON.stringify(dataP),
    success(data){
        console.log("succ "+data);
    },
    error:()=>{
        console.log('error ');
    }
})
```

Controller:intervenantController.php

```php
public static function addPostulantR(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json([
        'dataP' => Intervenant::addPostulantR($request->all())
    ]);
//The dataP is my json
}
```

Model: Intervenant.php

```php
public static function addPostulantR($data)
{
    //$test = json_decode($data);
    $id = 0;

    foreach($data as $dataP) {
        $id = DB::table('reponse')->insertGetId($dataP);
    }

    return $id;
}
```

Array: From my javascript

```
let dataP = [
              {
                fk_id_quest:1,
                fk_id_post:id,
                reponse : $("#descriptif_offre").val(),
                created_at:date.getTime()/1000,
              },
              { 
                fk_id_quest:2,
                fk_id_post:id,
                reponse : $("#descriptif_offre").val(),
                created_at:date.getTime()/1000,
              }
            ];
```

Thanks a lot..

Comment: It is harder to understand your intension here, Please explain what are this `dataP` contains. provide `response` table structure. Explain what are you actually trying yo store in the database.  Explain what is this `Intervenant`

Comment: DataP is an array, Intervenant is my model, basic MVC code...i just wanna post the DataP array inside my reponse table

Comment: if i try to store a simple object no prob, it works (not with the same model code), but if i try to store array of objects, it fail, the question is simple, how can i store array of objects into my reponse database

Comment: For an example, If you are storing to the `response` table. the model should called `Response`. But as I can see the model you uses is `Intervenant`.